# Workflow deployment in a multiple WFE farm environment

Tags: workflow, infopath, visual-studio, deployment

The issue is:,

- I change the visual studio workflow's initiation form via infopath
- create the wsp package again
- Retract and Remove it via the ca.
- Deploy the new package via powershell
- When I try to approve a document, the changes I've made in the initiation form comes bu the controls are disabled. When I try to approve it that way, it gives a "due to internal error workflow can not be started" error.

There are several servers in the dev environment. Do I have to stop the workflow feature in every one of them and restart?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Generally anyting that you do from browser results on content database change and you need NOT to do it on all servers. And so is the WSP deployment. Once you see the status of WSP as "Deployed" from Central Admin, it is deployed to all participating servers.

You just need to terminate the workflow once.